# Write output from for loop to a csv in python

Tags: python, string, csv, for-loop, export-to-csv

I am opening a csv called `Remarks_Drug.csv` which contains *product names* and mapped
*filenames* in consecutive columns. I am doing some operations on the product column 
to remove all string content after `+` character. After stripping the string from `+`
characters, I am storing the result in a variable called `product_patterns`.

Now I am opening a new `csv` and I want to write the output from the for loop into
two columns, the first one containing the `product_patterns` and the second one containing
the corresponding `filenames`.

What I am getting as output now is only the last row of the `output csv` that I am looking for.
I think I am not looping properly so that each row of `product_patterns` and filename gets
appended in the `output csv` file.

Can someone please help me with this.

Attaching code below:

```
import csv


with open('Remarks_Drug.csv', newline='', encoding ='utf-8') as myFile:
    reader = csv.reader(myFile)
    for row in reader:
        product = row[0].lower()
        #print('K---'+ product)
        filename = row[1]
        product_patterns = ', '.join([i.split("+")[0].strip() for i in product.split(",")])


        #print(product_patterns, filename)

    with open ('drug_output100.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['product_patterns', 'filename']
        print(fieldnames)
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        print(writer)
        #writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerow({'product_patterns':product_patterns, 'filename':filename})
```

Sample input:

```
    Film-coated tablet + TERIFLUNOMIDE, 2011-07-18 - Received approval letter_EN.txt
    Film-coated tablet + VANDETANIB,             2013-12-14 RECD Eudralink_Caprelsa II-28 - RSI - 14.12.2017.txt
    Solution for injection + MenQuadTT, 395_EU001930-PIP01-16_2016-02-22.txt
    Solution for injection + INSULIN GLARGINE,  2017-11-4 Updated PR.txt
    Solution for injection + INSULIN GLARGINE + LIXISENATIDE,   2017 12 12 Email Approval Texts - SA1006-.txt
```

Comment: Can you please post example data?

Comment: `csv.DictWriter` uses a dictionary for each row (with keys being the field names and values being the value for the corresponding cell), and you've only written one row.

Comment: Yeah, I am unable to iterate over it

Comment: Added example data in existing code.

Comment: Because, you have a list and not dictionary

Comment: Correct. Can you please suggest the code changes

Comment: Can you share the example data as text and not as image please?

Comment: Shared example input data. Please check

Comment: Thanks, the data are divided by the space char or by the comma?

Comment: It's a csv, I have copied the text from excel.

Comment: open with some txt editor please, and paste the data. Not from excel, or I can't know what char it use as delimiter

Comment: Please check now

Comment: Ok, thanks, just a couple of minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is the right way for you, if is not, tell me and we check.

```
import csv

with open('Remarks_Drug.csv') as myFile:
    reader = csv.reader(myFile)
    products_list = list()
    filenames_list = list()

    for row in reader:
        products_list.append(row[0].lower().split("+")[0].strip())
        filenames_list.append(row[1])

    for index, product in enumerate(products_list):
        with open ('drug_output100.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
            fieldnames = ['product_patterns', 'filename']
            print(fieldnames)
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            print(writer)
            writer.writerow({'product_patterns':product, 'filename':filenames_list[index]})
```

1. Open the **Remarks_Drug.csv** file and create two list where store the
   row value elaborated as you prefer.
2. Iterate on the product list and enumerate it so you have an index to
   use on the filename list.
3. Open the output file and append to it the result.

You can also use `pandas` to elaborate csv files, faster and in a smart way.

Here the **pandas** solution:

```
import pandas as pd

def select_real_product(string_to_elaborate):
    return string_to_elaborate.split('+')[0].strip()

df = pd.read_csv("Remarks_Drug.csv", delimiter=',', names=("product", "filename"))

df['product'] = df['product'].apply(select_real_product)

df.to_csv("drug_output100.csv", sep=',', na_rep='empty',index_label=False, index=False)
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Check also the pandas solution. I think is better and working with pandas is fun. You can do more with pandas and csv file.

Comment: Thanks. Sure, I will check and clarify with you if I have got any doubts

Comment: Ok well, I think that pandas is the best solution, for smallest files and also biggest files.

Comment: What's happend? Why you have removed my answer as correct?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I could tick more than 1, so it got removed for your answer. I hv corrected it.

Answer (score 3):

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

with open('Remarks_Drug.csv', newline='', encoding ='utf-8') as myFile:
    reader = csv.reader(myFile)
    mydrug = []
    for row in reader:
        product = row[0].lower()
        #print('K---'+ product)
        filename = row[1]
        product_patterns = ', '.join([i.split("+")[0].strip() for i in product.split(",")])
        mydrug.append([product_patterns, filename])

#     print(mydrug)

    df = pd.DataFrame(mydrug, columns=['product_patterns', 'filename'])
    print(df)
    df.to_csv('drug_output100.csv', sep=',', index=False)
```

This utilizes `pandas` library. If you're to deal with large `csv` files using `panda`s will be handy and efficient in terms of performance and memory. This is just an alternative solution for the above.